# Logic of arithmetic operators?

Tags: php

As far as I understand of arithmetic operators, the below code should output `15` yet it outputs `11` and not sure why.

```
echo $total = 3 - 1 * 2 + 10; //outputs: 11
```

Comment: Standard rules of mathematics (aka BODMAS): brackets, division/multiplication, Addition/Subtraction

Comment: You must be aware of BODMAS. Wrap your arithmetic in brackets as brackets takes priority over everything else.

Comment: why the hell would you think it would evaluate to 15?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd get 15 out of that equation in any case. Could it be that you meant to write `3 + 1..`?

Comment: Flagging as _Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)_

Answer (score 0):

It's left from right, */% first of -+:

1 * 2 after 3 - 2 after 1 + 10.

As @delboy1978uk said, use brackets to break the usual precedence as you want.

See the [PHP page about  that operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and [their precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: Not sure what output you are saying here..I think you have a typo.. `3-2` not `2-3`

Answer (score 0):

Use some brackets!

```
$total = ((3 - 1) * 2) + 10; // outputs 14
$total = 3 - (1 * 2) + 10; // outputs 11
$total = (3 - 1) * (2 + 10); // outputs 24
```

You get the idea!

Comment: $total = 3 - (1 * 2) + 10; // outputs 11 how to get this

Comment: the bit in brackets is calculated first, giving us 3 - 2 + 10, which equals 11.

Comment: after brackets perform Addition operation   (BODMAS)